# Divide percentage amongst text inputs

Tags: jquery

How goes it folks,

What would you say is the best way to split a percentage amongst different form inputs using Jquery?
Ie.

```
<input type="text" value="" name="inputOne" />
<input type="text" value="" name="inputTwo" />
<input type="text" value="" name="inputThree" />
<input type="text" value="" name="inputFour" />
```

The idea is on keyup of each of these inputs, the value is taken--subtracted from 100% and then be divided and set as the value of the other fields.

So ultimately if input 25 as the value of Inputone the rest of the fields should then look like:

```
<input type="text" value="25" name="inputTwo" />
<input type="text" value="25" name="inputThree" />
<input type="text" value="25" name="inputFour" />
```

As always, any help is appreciated

Comment: I'm lost on the "the value is taken--subtracted from 100%" part, could you elaborate?

Comment: sorry about that--so the value from the active input field (whichever one you're entering a percentage into) is taken and subtracted (maybe a better way)     100% minus the input value divided by total count of the other fields

Comment: So what's the problem, you described an algorithm, why not to write it?

Comment: wondering what the best method to execute the algorithm would be

Comment: Will there always be 4 inputs, or should it be dynamic?

Comment: You can try [keydown](http://api.jquery.com/keydown/) event or use a plugin like [jQuery textchange](http://zurb.com/playground/jquery-text-change-custom-event) to do it.

Comment: @ScottBeeson it will be dynami, BlueSmith thank you for the links, checking them out now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this approach..

```
$('input').on('keyup', function() {
    var val = this.value,
        $allInputs = $('input');
    if(val > 100) {
         $allInputs.val(100/$allInputs.length);   
    }
    else {
         var length 
         $('input').not(this).val( (100-val)/ ($allInputs.length-1)  ) ;  
    }
});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v64yz/)**

*Need to add some error checks though*

Answer (score 1):

Here is a dynamic solution that works based on a class with any number of divs.

```
$('.Maths').on('keyup', function() {
    var base = parseInt($(this).val());
    var count = $('.Maths').length;
    var rest = (100 - base) / (count - 1);
    $(this).siblings().val(rest.toString());
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/scottbeeson/RMksp/